# Looping Excel Macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm not overly familiar with macros on Excel VBA, so was looking for some help on the following:

Creating a template where the user will enter an unlimited number of products and users, creating a matrix with products along the top and users along the left hand side.

```
          Product 1 Product 2   Product 3
```

User A
User 1
User 2
User 3

There they will use "x" or 1 and 0 to signify what products are assigned to each users (can be multiple products). From there I need a macro (or potentially a formula I'm told could work) to populate another tab with one line for each user/product combination. I would need a looping macro to cycle through each line as there is no restriction on how many users/products the person using the template may enter).

User (column 1)     Product (column 2)

User A  Product 1

User A  Product 2

User 1  Product 2

User 2  Product 3

User 3  Product 3

User 3  Product 2

Comment: I've no experience with macros so was hoping something could be suggested that I could use! As far as I can fathom a standard front end formula would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Public Sub GetUserProductCombi()
    Const clngRowProducts As Long = 1    'Row containing product
    Const cintColUsers As Integer = 1   'Column containing users
    Const cstrSheetNameTemplate As String = "template"

    Dim lngRowCombi As Long
    Dim shtTemplate As Worksheet
    Dim shtCombi As Worksheet
    Dim lngRowLastUser As Long
    Dim intColLastProduct As Integer
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim intCol As Integer
    Dim strProduct As String
    Dim strUser As String
    Dim strValue As String

    Set shtTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cstrSheetNameTemplate)
    Set shtCombi = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()
    shtCombi.Name = "combi"

    'Determine last row with user
    lngRowLastUser = _
        shtTemplate.Cells(shtTemplate.Rows.Count, cintColUsers).End(xlUp).Row

    'Determine last column product
    intColLastProduct = _
        shtTemplate.Cells(clngRowProducts, shtTemplate.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    lngRowCombi = 1
    'Loop through all the cells
    For lngRow = clngRowProducts + 1 To lngRowLastUser
        For intCol = cintColUsers + 1 To intColLastProduct
            'Get value
            strValue = shtTemplate.Cells(lngRow, intCol)
            'Check if value is other than empty (string)
            If Trim(strValue) <> "" Then
                'Determine product and user
                strProduct = Trim(shtTemplate.Cells(clngRowProducts, intCol))
                strUser = Trim(shtTemplate.Cells(lngRow, cintColUsers))

                'Write to combi sheet if both user and product are not empty
                If (strUser <> "") And (strProduct <> "") Then
                    shtCombi.Cells(lngRowCombi, 1) = strUser
                    shtCombi.Cells(lngRowCombi, 2) = strProduct
                    lngRowCombi = lngRowCombi + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next intCol
    Next lngRow

    MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```